# How to add one element of a list of the values of a dictionary when mapping the dictionary with a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary whose keys match with one of the column of a pandas data frame I have. I want to add in a new column the values of this dictionary. However, the values of this dictionary are in a list.

```
dicts
{'A1BG': [('chr19', 58345178, '+', 5304388456)],
 'A1CF': [('chr10', 50799409, '+', 12173607359)],
 'A2M': [('chr12', 9067664, '+', 12341034620)],
 'A2ML1': [('chr12', 8822472, '+', 12341034620)],...}
```

I know how to add the complete list in a new column

```
loeuf['chromosome_hg38'] = loeuf['gene'].map(dicts)
```

But I don't know how to add only the value `ch19` instead of   `('chr19', 58345178, '+', 5304388456)]`

First row of loeuf

```
gene transcript canonical       obs_mis exp_mis oe_mis  mu_mis  possible_mis    obs_mis_pphen   exp_mis_pphen   ... exac_pLI    exac_obs_lof    exac_exp_lof    exac_oe_lof brain_expression    chromosome  start_position  end_position    new chromosome_hg38
0    A1BG       ENST00000263100 True    298.0   293.85  1.01410 0.000019        3115.0  104.0   101.3900        ... 9.064900e-05    8.0 12.301  0.65033        NaN  chr19   58856544    58864865    [(chr19, 58345178, +, 5304388456)]  chr19
```

Comment: `loeuf['gene'][0].map(dicts)` ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: post what is `loeuf` and what is `dicts`. The dictionary you posted is stored in which variable?

Comment: It was a typo. The structure of the dictionary is shown already. loeuf is a pandas data frame in which the column gene has the same values as the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: can you show what your dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I make dict just like you:

```
dict = {'A1BG': [('chr19', 58345178, '+', 5304388456)],
'A1CF': [('chr10', 50799409, '+', 12173607359)],
'A2M': [('chr12', 9067664, '+', 12341034620)],
'A2ML1': [('chr12', 8822472, '+', 12341034620)]}
```

next df:

```
loeuf = pd.DataFrame(['A1BG', 'A1CF', 'A2M', 'A2ML1'], columns=['gene'])
```

Finally I did what you wanted like that (using for loop):

```
for index, row in loeuf.iterrows():
    temp_value = dict[row.gene][0][0]
    loeuf['chromosome_hg38'][index] = temp_value
```

Output:

```
gene    chromosome_hg38
0   A1BG    chr19
1   A1CF    chr10
2   A2M chr12
3   A2ML1   chr12
```